# Numpy: indexing substrings of different lengths

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a large array of type "S1" obtained by concatenating many first name, last names pairs. For example:

```
>>> names
array([b'F', b'r', b'e', b'd', b'B', b'l', b'o', b'g', b's', b'A', b'n',
       b'n', b'S', b'm', b'i', b't', b'h', b'J', b'i', b'm', b'J', b'o',
       b'n', b'e', b's'], dtype='|S1')
```

Although much larger. You can see the names more easily:

```
>>> names.tobytes().decode()
'FredBlogsAnnSmithJimJones'
```

I have a separate integer array that tells me the positions of each name:

```
>>> idx
array([[ 4,  9],
       [12, 17],
       [20, 25]])
```

So we can find the nth person's first and last name:

```
>>> idx[1]
array([12, 17])
>>> idx[0,1]
9
>>>
```

So this allows me to recover the nth first, last name pair:

```
>>> names[9:12].tobytes().decode(), names[12:17].tobytes().decode()
('Ann', 'Smith')
```

The problem is: given an array of indexes for people *in arbitrary order* find the corresponding names. So from e.g. from `[2,0]` (as a numpy array) recover `[["Jim", "Jones"], ["Fred", Blogs"]]`. For example something like:

```
>>> get_names(names, np.array[2,0])
array([['Jim', 'Jones'],
       ['Fred', 'Blogs']], dtype='<U5')
```

although the dtype could be object here with python strings.

I can do this by generating indexes in python, but in practice I might have a long list of indexes and want to know if there's a way of doing the index generation in numpy to improve performance.

There is a reason for having the original data as one big contiguous array (sharing data using shared memory), so solutions involving converting the source data to anything containing object dtype won't work.

Although I've framed the question for my particular use case, the core question of how to obtain the appropriate indexes into the names array, doesn't really depend on the dtype of names.

Comment: Is there a reason to keep the original array as individual letters? If you want to retrieve the names by index, would it be ok to use `idx` once and create a new array `names2` that looks like `[["Fred", "Blogs"], ["Ann", "Smith"] ... ]` so that you can index it directly?

Comment: I edited to address that question.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the array of `S1` to bytestring with:

```
In [35]: astr = b''.join(arr)
In [36]: astr
Out[36]: b'FredBlogsAnnSmithJimJones'
```

If you want to decode that's fine.

Strings can be sliced just like arrays:

```
In [37]: (astr[9:12],astr[12:17])
Out[37]: (b'Ann', b'Smith')
```

But arrays can be indexed with arrays, which strings (and lists don't allow):

For example a numpy helper function can convert two slices into an array:

```
In [38]: np.r_[9:12,12:17]
Out[38]: array([ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
In [39]: arr[_]
Out[39]: array([b'A', b'n', b'n', b'S', b'm', b'i', b't', b'h'], dtype='|S1')
```

So that selects the relevant characters, but looses the split between first and last names.

So even with arrays I don't any way to "quickly" select a "random" set of first/last names.

I think your best best is to split the whole array into the names ahead of time, and then do your "random" selection after.  Selection on the fly from the flat runon array (or string) is not going to be fast.

For example use `array_split` to divide the array into a list of arrays, one for each name.  This in effect does a slice for each pair of numbers in the flattened `idx`.

```
In [45]: np.array_split(arr,idx.ravel())
Out[45]:
[array([b'F', b'r', b'e', b'd'], dtype='|S1'),
 array([b'B', b'l', b'o', b'g', b's'], dtype='|S1'),
 array([b'A', b'n', b'n'], dtype='|S1'),
 array([b'S', b'm', b'i', b't', b'h'], dtype='|S1'),
 array([b'J', b'i', b'm'], dtype='|S1'),
 array([b'J', b'o', b'n', b'e', b's'], dtype='|S1'),
 array([], dtype='|S1')]
In [46]: alist = np.array_split(arr,idx.ravel())
```

Then convert that to a list of strings:

```
In [47]: blist = [b''.join(x) for x in alist]
In [48]: blist
Out[48]: [b'Fred', b'Blogs', b'Ann', b'Smith', b'Jim', b'Jones', b'']
```

It is possible to index pairs from a list, but for convenience lets convert this to a 2 column array:

```
In [49]: barr = np.array(blist[:-1]).reshape(-1,2)
In [50]: barr
Out[50]:
array([[b'Fred', b'Blogs'],
       [b'Ann', b'Smith'],
       [b'Jim', b'Jones']], dtype='|S5')
In [51]: barr[[0,2]]
Out[51]:
array([[b'Fred', b'Blogs'],
       [b'Jim', b'Jones']], dtype='|S5')
```

`array_split` is effectively doing:

```
In [54]: [b''.join(arr[i:j]) for i,j in [[0,4],[4,9],[9,12],[12,17],[17,20],[20,25]]]
Out[54]: [b'Fred', b'Blogs', b'Ann', b'Smith', b'Jim', b'Jones']
```

I used the explicit list of lists because I didn't want to take time to derive the equivalent from `idx`.

### edit

Compare the size of the two arrays:

```
In [59]: arr.nbytes, barr.nbytes
Out[59]: (25, 30)

In [60]: arr.tobytes()
Out[60]: b'FredBlogsAnnSmithJimJones'
In [61]: barr.tobytes()
Out[61]: b'Fred\x00BlogsAnn\x00\x00SmithJim\x00\x00Jones'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Whilst I can do some preprocessing, it's important that I end up with a small number of large arrays, rather than a large number of small arrays. In my actual use case names is about a billion elements long, and idx is about 10 million long. I need to think a bit about this a bit more. I might end up using Numba or Cython.

Comment: If the names don't differ too widely in length, splitting the array into words, won't increase the overall memory use a lot. See the numbers I added.

Comment: It's not the total memory consumption, it's the mechanism I'm using to share this data between different processes - it needs to be quick and only really works well for a few blocks of memory. If I have millions of small blocks of memory it won't work the way I want. I can go back to the drawing board on the architecture, but I think a bit of performance testing with a naive python implementation + possibly a numba compiled variant is the thing to try.